# How to load kernel module with Magisk root but without custom kernel?

Tags: root-access, kernel, magisk

I am having a really hard time finding anything about this on Google which is not from 2011. I have a Samsung Galaxy S10+. I have rooted it with Magisk **without** TWRP, i.e. no custom recovery or custom kernel. I want OTA updates without having to delete everything on my phone just to update, that is why I use Magisk without TWRP.

What I need is drivers for my WiFi adapter `TP-Link TL-WN7220`. I know that to be able to install a driver into the kernel, that means a custom kernel and then you would not be able to have OTA updates which defeats the above purpose.

My question is, is there a way to load a driver, even if it is temporary like loading a kernel module on Linux? On Linux this does not require a reboot, can this be done similarly on Android, so I will keep my stock kernel but still be able to run the WiFi adapter?

Comment: [Is it possible to add a driver to my kernel without flashing a new kernel?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/214736/218526)

Answer (score 2):

> I know that to be able to install a driver into the kernel, that means a custom kernel and then you would not be able to have OTA updates which defeats the above purpose.

You can't have OTA updates with Magisk installed because flashing Magisk modifies `boot` partition in which kernel binary lives. Before OTA update, you will have to uninstall Magisk which will restore original `boot.img`, backed up in `/data`. So at the moment you can do whatever you want with kernel. That will be reversed with Magisk uninstall.

> is there a way to load a driver, even if it is temporary like loading a kernel module on Linux?

Yes you can load kernel modules just as you do on Linux. But for that you have to rebuild kernel with the required module, or it should be compatible with installed kernel if built separately.

The installed kernel should be built with `CONFIG_MODULES=y` in order to load modules. Make sure the version of kernel source code tree or that of header files match with installed kernel version. Otherwise dependencies may break resulting in `Unknown symbol in module` type of errors. Also, if kernel is signed (`CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_FORCE`), modules must be signed with the same key to avoid `required keys not available` error.